# Integrate external script with parameters in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading

I am trying to integrate intercom.io in my AngularJS application.

The script has some parameters to configure before the full loading:

```
<script id="IntercomSettingsScriptTag">
  window.intercomSettings = {
    // TODO: The current logged in user's email address.
    email: "john.doe@example.com",
    // TODO: The current logged in user's sign-up date as a Unix timestamp.
    created_at: 1234567890,
    app_id: "95b20cd5364bab3a2136e252d2862b8136aabe7e"
  };
</script>
<!-- Init script -->
<script>(function(){var w=window;var ic=w.Intercom;if(typeof ic==="function"){ic('reattach_activator');ic('update',intercomSettings);}else{var d=document;var i=function(){i.c(arguments)};i.q=[];i.c=function(args){i.q.push(args)};w.Intercom=i;function l(){var s=d.createElement('script');s.type='text/javascript';s.async=true;s.src='https://static.intercomcdn.com/intercom.v1.js';var x=d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];x.parentNode.insertBefore(s,x);}if(w.attachEvent){w.attachEvent('onload',l);}else{w.addEventListener('load',l,false);}};})()</script>
```

I tried to use {{data.email}} to replace the email but unfortunately, the init script get loaded before the intercomSettings. ng-cloak is not very useful for me because it has been designed only for presentation purposes.

I am not sure in which direction I should look for.
To test my code: http://plnkr.co/edit/2PJNLukBx0cTOPZXNwqs?p=preview

You should get a little question mark at the bottom right of the window if it works.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you already found a solution, but you should take a look on this:

https://github.com/maxiperezc/angular-intercom
it basically wrapped intercom script into angular, so you can use within your application using directives.

This is an improved version of https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-intercom - they removed some unnecessary code

Answer (score 0):

I updated angular-intercom to the latest intercom api if you're still interested. The service has been simplified for the user with a better way of handling async script loading
https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-intercom